# Firefox external onfly interaction

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, sqlite

Background: I'm trying to make a set of scripts to allow myself edit stylish themes in external editor (vi in my case). In order to do that I store styles.css as external file, edit it and upload with a simple script to stylish.sqlite database. It works perfect except my changes are not applied immediately (like it is in case I save changes for the same theme in builtin firefox stylish editor). Which annoys me a bit.

The issue: It looks like the possible solution would be turn off all styles and then turn it on back. 
It can be done via switching `extensions.stylish.styleRegistrationEnabled` option in about:config (or simply a button from addons panel).

Though button clicking is annoying. I love full automation. 
Therefore I'm trying to find the way to reload it from outside (it seems like a possible solution to me).
Is it possible? How it can be done?

ps. I use FF44.

Comment: Have you tried [Use external editor to edit style on Stylish extension](https://gist.github.com/LouCypher/3218906) or [Stylish Custom](https://choggi.org/misc/Stylish-Custom/) both of which allow stylish to use an external editor.

Comment: Thank you for the link, though my idea is to store the style completely outside (in git repo) and upload changes from there into stylish with immediate update. without using any complex click combinations inside firefox (like styilish → edit addon →open in whatever editor → save → switch to the correct tab). it's annoying :)

Comment: Ah, OK. That wasn't immediately obvious from my first read of your question.